# Obtain all possible combinations of logical variables without specifying the number of elements

Tags: r, binary, combinations

I'm trying to get all the combinations of a vector. I have

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
```

I need to get all the possible combinations without specifying the number of elements needed and without taking into account the order (the solution `{2,3,1}` is the same as `{1,2,3}`). For example, the result would be:

```
{}
{3}
{2}
{2,3}
{1}
{1,3}
{1,2}
{1,2,3}
```

An approximation would be to make the following table:

[image: Tabla lógica]

I am sure that there must be some function that performs this task instead of creating the table and forming the solutions from it, since it is not very tedious.

Comment: You are looking for the Power set. Check out the `powerset` function from the library `rje`.

Comment: @JosephWood oh yes, this was I looking for, you can put this comment like an answer for check it?

Comment: I am not able to post as this question has been marked as a duplicate. Either way, I'm glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Use `expand.grid`

```
out <- expand.grid(rep(list(c(1, 0)), length(x)))
out
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    1    1    1
#2    0    1    1
#3    1    0    1
#4    0    0    1
#5    1    1    0
#6    0    1    0
#7    1    0    0
#8    0    0    0
```

If we need the combinations - as a list - we might do

```
split(out * col(out), 1:nrow(out))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$`2`
#[1] 0 2 3
#
#$`3`
#[1] 1 0 3
#
#$`4`
#[1] 0 0 3
#
#$`5`
#[1] 1 2 0
#
#$`6`
#[1] 0 2 0
#
#$`7`
#[1] 1 0 0
#
#$`8`
#[1] 0 0 0
```

Or if we don't need the `0`s we might do

```
by(out * col(out), 1:nrow(out), FUN = function(x) x[x != 0])
```

(`by` is short for `lapply(split(...` )

Comment: I may not have explained myself well, I do not need to create the table, I need to create the combinations, the use of the table has been an example in which I approach the solution

Comment: @Draggluon Updated my answer. Hope this helps.